# youtube Api key is the same with Developer key?

Tags: android, eclipse, api, youtube, key

I just try to copy and paste my youtube api key to ***YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.0.0 sample*** in eclipse, but it gives only error and does not accept the code
What should i do? 
and what about absolute key? i tried it also but it gives error too.


*The Code Page of DeveloperKey.java*:

// Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

package com.examples.youtubeapidemo;

/**
 * Static container class for holding a reference to your YouTube Developer Key.
 */
public class DeveloperKey {

/**
   * Please replace this with a valid API key which is enabled for the 
   * YouTube Data API v3 service. Go to the 
   * [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) to
   * register a new developer key.
   */
  public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = **AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxYo-WQxxxxs78**;

}

***ERROR LOGS***; 
**AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxZ8Yo** cannot be resolved to a variable   DeveloperKey.java   /YouTubeAndroidAPIDemo/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo  line 16 Java Problem

**WQPxxx78** cannot be resolved to a variable   DeveloperKey.java   /YouTubeAndroidAPIDemo/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo  line 16 Java Problem


**i think it has a problem because of  *-*  between Yo and WQ ?**

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the api key in double quotes.
public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxYo-WQxxxxs78";